# How to delete data from the list view after checked in android

Tags: android

Hi the issue is that the selected data's are appearing in the list view, but actually we would like to delete the data's from the list view which is checked means position deletion

can anybody join us to resolve the problem

coding

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(data!=null){enter code here
            Bundle bundle = data.getExtras();
            if(requestCode ==1){
                selectedConatcts = bundle.getStringArrayList("sel_contacts");
                Log.v("", "Selected contacts-->"+selectedConatcts);
                if(selectedConatcts.size()<0){

                }else{
                    for(int i =0;i<selectedConatcts.size();i++){
                        RelativeLayout lnr_inflate = (RelativeLayout)View.inflate(thisActivity, R.layout.contacts_inflate, null);

                        // EditText edt = (EditText)lnr_inflate.findViewById(R.id.edt_contact);

                        String selectednames =selectedConatcts.get(i) ;

                        List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(selectednames)); 

                        final ListView edt = (ListView)lnr_inflate.findViewById(R.id.edt_contact);

                        ArrayAdapter<String> adaptercon = new ArrayAdapter<String>(thisActivity, android.R.layout.select_dialog_multichoice,stringList);
                        edt.setAdapter(adaptercon);
                        edt.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
                        edt.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                                    View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                 final int len = edt.getCount();
                                    final SparseBooleanArray checked = edt.getCheckedItemPositions();

                                    for(int i =0;i<len;i++){


                                        if (checked.get(i)) {
//                                            selectedContacts.add(names[i]);
//                                          selectedConatcts.get(i);
//                                          selectedConatcts.remove(i);
                                            selectedConatcts.remove(phone_nos[i]);
                                            contactdisp.removeViewAt(i);


                                           //you can you this array list to next activity
//                                         do whatever you want with the checked item 
                                         }
//                                      selectedConatcts.get(i);
                                        System.out.println("i m in check button cheked"+selectedConatcts.get(i));


                                    }       
                                selectedConatcts.remove(phone_nos[arg2]);
                                contactdisp.removeViewAt(arg2);


                            }
                        });

                        contactdisp.addView(lnr_inflate);
}}}}
```

Comment: remove from array list and reload the list view

Comment: Please post the code for your ListView

Comment: Hi thanks signare here I need individual data deletion needs to be performed not the entire list

Comment: hi partisan I have included the coding help us

Answer (score 0):

1. Better check whether the checkbox is checked or not code  write under the button_click
2. Remove Items
   `remove selectedConatcts.remove(phone_nos[arg2]);    contactdisp.removeViewAt(arg2);`